# Load sql file in database using php

Tags: php, sql, import, load

I want to load data from sql file which is located on linux server to database.

I tried like this.

```
$query = "LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/technoho/public_html/gpstracking/system/application/controllers/backup/uploads/28_07_11_14_11_07.sql' 
INTO TABLE `backup` 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\', \'' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
STARTING BY 'INSERT'";
```

This query works with local system file, but I want to load data from server file. 
I think I am wrong in giving path for server file.

Comment: Simple answer is yes your path is probably wrong. You need to check with your linux server host to determine the correct path.

Comment: If the file is on different server than MySQL server then you need to use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`

Comment: thnx for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

MySqlDumper is the best tool to use for such a job
[here is a link](http://www.mediafire.com/?w584yc8z3piwyca)